# How to handle MongoDB schema validation?

Tags: mongodb, validation

Reading the MongoDB [manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/schema-validation/), at the bottom, it say's that schema validation can be bypassed using the bypassDocumentValidation when doing an insert or update.

If I want to make sure that no one can put incorrect data into the database, should I only offer access through a API that can enforce these rules without them being bypassed?

Comment: U can use mongoose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two ways:

1. as you said, simply wrap the request to mongo in your own method.
2. you can authentify to mongo with a user which cannot bypass validation. A bit trickier to do.

See mongo docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#bypassDocumentValidation

Answer (score 0):

If you're in a Node environment, you can use [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com/), though this kind of defeats the point of using a NoSQL document database. Otherwise, as stated, you can write your own validation logic.